# Как отвечать на MessageBox скриптом

Tags: python, python-3.x, messagebox

Как отвечать на всплывающее окно MessageBox скриптом python?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос с помощи WindowsAPI.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con


hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "<window_title_name>")
if hwnd != 0:
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_COMMAND, win32con.IDYES, 0)
```